# Deploying with Bower

Tags: jquery, npm, bower

So say I am developing with bower and I have a list of my dependencies in my bower.json file.  Since I am in development mode I want to have the latest stable version of the major release I'm on.

```
"dependencies": {
    "jquery": "1.*"
}
```

In order to use these files in the client I am doing something like:

```
<script src="/bower_components/jquery/index.js"></script>
```

This is nice when developing but what happens when I want to deploy and control caching by changing the file name?  For example I release my site with jquery 1.05 and develop for a while and want to release a new version. I update my jquery to 1.10 through bower but everyone that viewed my site has jquery 1.05 in their cache (the file name has not changed).

Is there tools to automate this ?  Essentially I would want to update jquery and have the folder name update with the version info.  And reference like:

```
<script src="/bower_components/jquery-1.10/index.js"></script>
```

I know I can do something like:

```
"dependencies": {
    "jquery-1.10": "1.10"
}
```

That would produce the desired directory structure but it isn't very automated.

Comment: You should really check out [**grunt**](http://gruntjs.com/) (it's a NodeJS based JavaScript build tool), and specifically the [**grunt-rev plugin**](https://github.com/cbas/grunt-rev), which is bundled by default if you're using yeoman. Oh yeah, and you should definitely have a look at [**yeoman**](http://yeoman.io/), too. :)

Comment: @EliranMalka thanks for the info, I actually am using grunt.  Unfortunately that plugin is pretty much tied to having a yeoman project which won't play nicely with our preexisting project.

Comment: Oh I see... Perhaps you can embed grunt-usemin without rebuilding the project with yeoman (anyhow there shouldn't be anything preventing you from using these plugins on a non-yeoman project).

Comment: True but it is pretty much tied to yeoman.  It busts the cache by changing the file name based off hashed value of the file contents.  That would be a pain to maintain without using yeoman.  Much easier to create a folder based off the version of the bower component.