# How to deploy client side dependencies on webserver?

Tags: javascript, bower

I have done some web developing using Python and Django. I use virtualenv to make a bootstrap script that can install all my Python dependencies on a server. I have a repository for the code I have written myself, and in that repository are two file (beside my code): requirements.txt and bootstrap.py. Using the bootstrap script, it installs all the dependencies on the server.

Now I would like something similar for the client side dependencies. E.g. jQuery, jQuery-ui and bootstrap. Currently I manually download the files and put them in the static folder on the server.

I have run into Bower, and I understand that it can indeed download various js-libraries. But I don't see how to use it in an elegant way. E.g. for jQuery it downloads the entire jQuery repository, which means both a dist folder and a src folder, containing tons of files. All I need is the jQuery.min.js.

Well, wide question, what is the neat way of automating the deployment of client side dependencies?

Comment: Why not use `requests`, an elegant python HTTP client, to automate the downloads? After all, urls are fixed

Comment: After looking around, e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21560922/deploying-with-bower), it seems like it is an accepted way to just make bower_components a library for static files. I guess this is the easiest way to handle client side dependencies. It just seemed wrong to me, to expose an hundreds file, when only a handful are needed.

Answer (score 0):

you can use composer

```
{
    "require": {
        "jquery/jquery": "*"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "jquery/jquery",
                "version": "1.8.2",
                "dist": {
                    "url": "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js",
                    "type": "file"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```